# Default preloader doesn't work / Best way to load large graphics

Tags: flash, preloader, flash-cs5

The site in question is http://beta.motionnotion.com

The big Flash header is like 800kb, but for some reason, the default Flash preloader isn't working.

Two questions:

1. What's the best way to preload big bitmap graphics (Such as the scrolling bg; the android head)
2. How should I preload this movie, and why doesn't the default Adobe Flash preloader fire?

Thanks, and apologies if this question is too vague -- please comment and I can expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a preloader, compress images as much and reuse as often as possible.
2. There is no such thing as a "default Flash preloader".  You have to program your own.

There is no preloader code in your header file. Nothing will happen, unless you add some.
Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/) to see how it could be done.

Comment: I'm referring to the TLF preloader; I think this is a Flash CS5-specific thing, you can change its settings by going to: Publish settings -> Flash (label) -> Settings (button) -> Library path (label)

Comment: It's a setting specific to Flash Player 10.1 (Beta) content, and it is used only for preloading runtime shared libraries. Check out the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/fl/rsl/RSLPreloader.html  If you haven't declared a runtime shared library (which I assume you haven't, because only one SWF was loaded on the page), this setting will do nothing at all.  Which ultimately leads to my original statement: There is no such thing as a "default Flash preloader". You have to program your own. ;)

Comment: Insert big "OHHHHHHHHHHHH!" here. I was getting confused because people were talking about that loading instead of their own preloader; thanks!